# passing html tags arguments in django template to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I want to pass HTML string as argument in javascript, in django template.
Here it is:
I have bunch of links, which they are in my database.
I can access these links via ***{% for link in links %} {{ link }} {% endfor %}*** in my django template.
for example, I can access a certain link name with using ***{{ link.name }}***, but I also have content specified to every links; like `{{ link.content }}`.

the problem is; in my template I have a sidebar nav which contains several link's urls, and I want to display the content of clicked link in that page. for that, I wrote a javascript function named display:

```
<script>
        function display(str){
                   document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = str:                     
                      }
</script>
```

which will access:

```
<div id="cont"> </div>
```

here it is:

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="{{ link.link }}" onclick="display('{{ link.content }}')">{{ link.name }}</a>
```

in the code above, the display function doesn't work.
I mean, when I click the link in sidebar, it doesn't show any content, literally nothing.
but for test, when I changed the display argument ***{{ link.content }}*** to something else like `'<h1>hello<h1>'`, it worked.
**p.s: my link's content is an inline html tags like:** `'<h1><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp'`
and note that I put my `<script> ...` at bottom of the `<body>`.
I will be very thankful for any helps and guides.

Comment: are you able to console.log(str) and see the content in the console?

Comment: no... but I see this error when I check the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: share the screenshot please

Answer (score 0):

First, could you check if your **{{ link.content }}** is not empty. Also, try putting the script tag on top.

Comment: it's not empty, and I put the script at the top. but nothing happened.

Comment: Since you are using " " it has a slightly different meaning and usage than of ' '. trying using without ' '.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="display('{{ link.content }}')"
```

don't enclose it in single inverted commas while inserting link.content

use:

```
onclick="display({{ link.content }})"
```